# Configuring Ruby on Rails to run under Apache on Windows 64-bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, windows-7, 64-bit

I've inherited the maintenance and development of a Ruby on Rails site that runs on Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.2. While we try to deploy to Linux servers using Passenger as much as possible, my boss has told me that there we must be able to deploy to Windows at times for our clients.

I have installed my Rails app fine and it works perfectly when I test with the Webrick server. I have also installed Apache 2.2 which is serving up generic HTML pages perfectly. However, when I try to run my Rails app under Apache I get a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error

There is no error listed in the Apache logs but when I check the RoR logs it does show

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2012:10:31:02 +1000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 323
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2012:10:31:02 +1000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 503 323
```

and

```
[Thu Aug 09 10:31:06 2012] [error] proxy: BALANCER: (balancer://mmapscluster). All workers are in error state
[Thu Aug 09 10:31:07 2012] [error] proxy: BALANCER: (balancer://mmapscluster). All workers are in error state
```

As you may have guessed we are running Mongrel as a proxy server for performance reasons.

When I removed all of the proxying from the Apache configuration (incidentally restarting Apache is not enough for the proxy config - I had to reboot the entire machine), I got a seemingly endless list of the following Apache errors,

```
[notice] Parent: Created child process 1944
[notice] Child 1944: Child process is running
[notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I have gone round and round on this and I've checked my config against a working installation that we have but I cannot see any differences in the setup. The only real difference is that the working one is running on a 32-bit machine and the failing one is running on a 64-bit machine.

Could this be the problem? Has anybody else had any similar types of problems running Apache on 64-bit machines?

Comment: Never had any problems running apache/rails on 64-bit machines. I have however had TREMENDOUS difficulty running on windows, so I wouldn't e surprised if 64-bit windows was not supported. Have you thought about trying it under cygwin/vm?

Comment: I would love to if I could but since the clients don't have the expertise to administrate anything other than Windows I don't have much choice

Comment: This is probably horrible advice, but I would take a look at vagrant. It is a low maintenance solution to virtualization specially useful for hosting webapps. http://vagrantup.com/ You basically build the vm, and distribute it along with the app. Starting the server is no harder then booting Apache.